# jqXHR object's responseText being returned as html rather than json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iis

On staging, in the error callback, the jqXHR.responseText is being returned as a html string but locally it works perfectly & a json object gets returned in the very same error callback, I'm making a typical asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request using JQuery.

Snippet of the error callback is shown below

```
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    l.stop();
                    l.setProgress(0);
                    $("#error").show();
                    try {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                        if (data && data.Message && data.Message.length > 0) {
                            $("#error .message").html(data.Message);
                        } else {
                            $("#error .message").html("An unexpected error has occurred.  Please contact support for assistance.");
                        }
                    } catch (ex) {
                        $("#error .message").html("An unexpected error has occurred.  Please contact  support for assistance.");
                    }

                }
```

The jqXHR.responseText that gets returned on staging is shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
      <title>500 - Internal server error.</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         <!--
            body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
            fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
            h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
            h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
            h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
            #header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
            background-color:#555555;}
            #content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
            .content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
            -->
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="header">
         <h1>Server Error</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
         <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
               <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
               <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Given below is the image when i run this locally, and as you can see the json object gets returned

[image]

And, here's what happens on staging

[image]

The version of IIS on staging is 7.5.7600.16385, and the JQuery version is 2.1.4

Could someone let me know what might be wrong or where I should start looking to fix this issue.

Here' the full code of the ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateAdjustment", "AccredScoring")',
                dataType : "json",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                    l.stop();
                    var oTT = TableTools.fnGetInstance('adjustments');

                    var row = oTT.fnGetSelected()[0];
                    var headRow = $('#adjustments').children('thead');

                    if (currentId == data["Id"]) {
                        $('#adjustments').dataTable().fnUpdate(data, row);

                        $(headRow).notify('Adjustment Successfully Updated', 'success', 'top');
                    } else {
                        $('#adjustments').dataTable().fnAddData(data);

                        $(headRow).notify('New Adjustment Created', 'success', 'top');
                    }

                    $('#EditModal').modal('hide');

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    l.stop();
                    l.setProgress(0);
                    $("#error").show();
                    try {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                        if (data && data.Message && data.Message.length > 0) {
                            $("#error .message").html(data.Message);
                        } else {
                            $("#error .message").html("An unexpected error has occurred.  Please contact NCQA technical support for assistance.");
                        }
                    } catch (ex) {
                        $("#error .message").html("An unexpected error has occurred.  Please contact NCQA technical support for assistance.");
                    }

                },
                xhr: function () {
                    myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (myXhr.upload) {
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',
                            function (evt) {
                                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                    var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total);
                                    l.setProgress(percentComplete);
                                }
                            },
                            false);
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },
            });
```

If I remote desktop into the staging environment then on accessing the staging url all works well

Comment: Maybe an url or routing problem...can you post the full code of your ajax call and the url values for dev and production environment?

Comment: The network tab in the browser debugger might provide a hint.  The problem is on the end point

Comment: the success callback works fine but in Firefox in console tab I see the following error message Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"
 

...ion(n[u])&&n[u];t[e[1]](function(){var n=o&&o.apply(this,arguments);n&&i.isFunct...

Comment: @Hackerman - I've added the ajax call code to the end of the question itself

Comment: @Roberto - so, from the server when the inputs are not valid the response status code being returned is 500 - locally this does not seem to be an issue but on staging this status code might be stopping the json object from being returned, if I simply return a response status code of 400 do you think it might work?

Comment: @Hackerman url for dev is http://localhost/Nnnn.Evv.Web/AccredScoring/UpdateAdjustment and staging is http://staging.nnnn.org/Evv/AccredScoring/UpdateAdjustment

Comment: Can you post the controller method?

Comment: @Hackerman - here's what was missing          Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true. all works well now. thanks for looking into this